# Extend JS Boolean.prototype fail

Tags: javascript, boolean, prototype

I want to do this:

```
a = false;

a.toggle();

console.log(a) // -> true;
```

So I created this:

```
Boolean.prototype.toggle = function (){this = !this; return this;}
```

But Its just doesnt work. I tried many similar versions also with valueOf and whatever, but always fail.

I suspect that `Boolean` object has no setter method @ its `prototype`. But May be you guys can help with this.

Thanks in advance.

(Please dont answer "Why `a = !a` doesnt good for you?")

Comment: JavaScript primitives are immutable (the same as in most languages). This isn't going to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Im not going to ask why `a = !a` is no good for you; Im going to *tell* you it's the right way to do it! Think of other programmers before you go adding pointless extensions to the language. **Every** programmer will understand what `!a` does!

Comment: Boolean.prototype.toggle has been accepted by Chrome. And its in the Object, but it doesnt do the expected functionality :s

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can never assign to `this` in javascript so `this = !this` won't work.

Second of all, it does not appear that the Boolean object has a setter.  It has `valueOf()` and it has `toString()`.

This is the closest I can come to it:

```
Boolean.prototype.toggle = function (){return !this.valueOf();}

var a = false;
var b = a.toggle();

console.log(b) // -> true;​
```

Comment: Yes, thats the closest I got too. But cant change the boolean value from the toggle func